# CSS position arrow elements - Jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I am trying to position two arrow elements in the following code.  They should be to the direct left and right of the quotes, and I will be wanting to hook them into the jQuery cycle to move things left or right.

http://jsfiddle.net/k8UvP/28/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#txtRotate').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollRight',
    timeout: 3,
    cleartypeNoBg: true
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cycle plugin has this feature built in using `prev` and `next

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtRotate').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight',
        timeout: 0,
        next: '#right',
        prev: '#left'
    });
});
```

[**Example jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UvP/29/)

However with the effect you're using (`scrollRight`) it's hard to tell the difference between the two arrows (impossible with only two elements actually). You likely want to use the `scrollHorz` effect instead

You really should look at the [plugin page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), it has a lot of useful examples (including one with previous and next buttons). It could have helped with the last question you posted as well

**EDIT**

Usually if you want the arrows to be positioned in reference to the element you'd put it as a child. However since cycle elements don't allow that, you'll have to use jQuery like the following. It fires on window resize so it can always stay in line with the unusually positioned cycle element

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var midWay = $('#txtRotate').offset().top + $('#txtRotate').height() / 2;
    console.log(midWay);
    $('#left').css('top', midWay);
    $('#right').css('top', midWay);
}).resize();
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/k8UvP/30/)

Comment: I guess my question is more how to have the arrows appear to the left / right of the quote divs, so that they are all horizontally aligned.

Comment: @user1110562 Updated to suite your needs

Comment: @user1110562 Any more feedback?